# Using @model dynamic in a Partial nested in a subfolder throws RuntimeBinderException

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, dynamic, model

I'm having some problems finding a solution for this, though it seems straight-forward enough, and I imagine someone else must have run into this issue before.

Using MVC/Razor 4, I am trying to render a partial using a dynamic model.
To organize things, I have placed my partials in a sub-folder within the same view folder.

When the partial in question is moved to the sub-folder, it throws a RuntimeBinderException with an exception message saying that 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Id' (the parameter I am trying to access).

This works perfectly fine when the partial is located in the same folder.

This structure works fine

- Views/Orders/Details.cshtml
- Views/Orders/_PartialWithDynamicModel.cshtml

This structure causes the exception

- Views/Orders/Details.cshtml
- Views/Orders/MyPartials/_PartialWithDynamicModel.cshtml

**CODE**

**Details.cshtml**

```
    @Html.Partial("MyPartials/_PartialWithDynamicModel", new { Id = 54 } )
```

**_PartialWithDynamicModel.cshtml**

```
    @model dynamic

    @ { //The following line throws the RuntimeBinderException
        int id = Model.Id; }
```

Any thoughts? If I move the partial into the same folder as the view, everything works fine.

Comment: why not ``@model int``

Comment: I'm trying to pass in more than just the id, and I would prefer to not have to create a class just for this Partial.

Comment: The name you specify in Details.cshtml is not the same as the partial you are debugging.  I assume you made a mistake here?  You really need to post accurate code otherwise we go down the wrong path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you can't pass an anonymous type to an object in a separate assembly.  They are created as "internal" types, and thus cannot be passed externally. Views are generated dynamically at runtime into their own assemblies.

Instead, use an ExpandoObject, like this:

```
@{ var myExpando = new ExpandoObject();
   myExpando.Id = 54; }
@Html.Partial("MyPartials/_PutOnHoldForm",  myExpando)
```

A better choice, however, would be to just pass a ViewDataDictionary, or perhaps use Tuples.

There is also the DynamicViewPage extension in the MVC futures project that allows you to do this as well without the expand object.

http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/using-the-features-of-asp-net-mvc-3-futures

(note, it says MVC3, but there is an MVC5 version of futures in Nuget)

Comment: OK... However, I must assume that my nested partials are also being placed in a separate assembly, as passing an anonymous object works when the partial is placed in the same folder as the view. You really need to post accurate answers otherwise we go down the wrong path

Comment: @Nicholas - if it works as you suggest, then it's probably an accident that it does.  You can't trust that this will always be the case, and it could break in the future.  There is no guarantee that any dynamically compiled object will stay in the same assembly.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, and I get the runtime exception even with ExpandoObject and @model dynamic:  'System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject' does not contain a definition for 'id'.